# android:layout_alignParentBottom,android:layout_alignParentRight not positioning correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I am learning google android.so help me with this.i am trying to position the text at the bottom right end.but its not working.any input is appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.dredd.happybirthday.MainActivity">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="happy birthday srikanth"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="from dayakar "
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
         />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: put it in relative layout

Comment: use linearlayout or relative layout

Comment: how can i do that.right now i am using andorid studio.it says constraintlayout

Comment: are you completely fresher to android. check below answer

Comment: yeah i am fresher

Comment: ok check answer below and do accordingly

Answer (score 0):

try this user `RelativeLayout` change your `layout` like below code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="happy birthday srikanth"
        />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="from dayakar "
        />

      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/disha"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:text="from dayakar "
    />
```

Comment: what happens with layout?

Comment: it remains same.nothing is happening

Comment: So try read this https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1 to better understand constrait layout.